# custom framework giving error when included file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have a custom framework that I created named CCServices. When I try to implement it into my project, Setec, I get the following warnings.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/lindsey.vastola/Desktop/Setec/iOS/Setec/Setec/Frameworks/CCServices.framework/CCServices, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/lindsey.vastola/Desktop/Setec/iOS/Setec/Setec/Frameworks/CCServices.framework/CCServices
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/lindsey.vastola/Desktop/Setec/iOS/Setec/Setec/Frameworks/CCSocket.framework/CCSocket, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/lindsey.vastola/Desktop/Setec/iOS/Setec/Setec/Frameworks/CCSocket.framework/CCSocket (2 slices)
```

Then I get the following errors when I reference some controllers in the framework.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Conversation", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Conversation in CaptionsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I get rid of these? I have tried different solutions but nothing worked. Please note that CCSocket is written in Objective C and Setec is in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

the framework was missing in the link binary with libraries list.